# Dynamic "across row" relative frequency

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with n variables (3 in the example but varies) and I'd like to find the relative frequency of those variable in relation to each other. They are always named the same, prefix followed by numeric sequence.

```
have <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x3 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
  )

want <-
  have |>
  mutate(
    x1_prop = x1 / (x1 + x2 + x3),
    x2_prop = x2 / (x1 + x2 + x3),
    x3_prop = x3 / (x1 + x2 + x3))
```

I think a solution in dplyr could use `mutate(across` but having trouble figuring out syntax...

```
want <-
  have |>
  mutate(across(everything()), . / rowSums(.)) # does not work
```

Answer (score 5):

Several things:

- Use anonymous functions with `~` (alternatively you can use `\(x)` or `function`)
- Use `pick(everything())` inside the `across` call to signify you want to get the sum of all columns. If you only use `.`, or `.x`, you'll get the sum of the current column only.

```r
have |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x / rowSums(pick(everything())), 
                .names = "{col}_prop"))

#    x1 x2 x3   x1_prop   x2_prop    x3_prop
# 1   9  5  2 0.5625000 0.3125000 0.12500000
# 2   6  4  6 0.3750000 0.2500000 0.37500000
# 3   9  6  1 0.5625000 0.3750000 0.06250000
# 4   8  7  8 0.3478261 0.3043478 0.34782609
# 5   1  8  7 0.0625000 0.5000000 0.43750000
# 6   9  3  9 0.4285714 0.1428571 0.42857143
# 7   7  4  8 0.3684211 0.2105263 0.42105263
# 8   3  5  5 0.2307692 0.3846154 0.38461538
# 9  10  8 10 0.3571429 0.2857143 0.35714286
# 10  5  2  6 0.3846154 0.1538462 0.46153846
# 11  3 10  1 0.2142857 0.7142857 0.07142857
# 12 10  8  2 0.5000000 0.4000000 0.10000000
# 13  3  7  6 0.1875000 0.4375000 0.37500000
# 14  4  4 10 0.2222222 0.2222222 0.55555556
# 15  2  7  4 0.1538462 0.5384615 0.30769231
# 16  2  3  2 0.2857143 0.4285714 0.28571429
# 17  3  9  1 0.2307692 0.6923077 0.07692308
# 18  8  6  2 0.5000000 0.3750000 0.12500000
# 19  2  2  8 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.66666667
# 20  7  4  3 0.5000000 0.2857143 0.21428571
```

Comment: Haven't seen `pick()` before - very cool!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R way using `prop.table()` on the data.

```r
have <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
    x3 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
  )

props <- prop.table(as.matrix(have), 1)
colnames(props) <- paste(colnames(props), "prop", sep="_")
cbind(have, 
      props
)
#>    x1 x2 x3   x1_prop    x2_prop   x3_prop
#> 1   8  5  3 0.5000000 0.31250000 0.1875000
#> 2   3  5  6 0.2142857 0.35714286 0.4285714
#> 3   9  6  9 0.3750000 0.25000000 0.3750000
#> 4   8 10  7 0.3200000 0.40000000 0.2800000
#> 5   6 10  8 0.2500000 0.41666667 0.3333333
#> 6  10  5  4 0.5263158 0.26315789 0.2105263
#> 7  10  8  4 0.4545455 0.36363636 0.1818182
#> 8   7  5  8 0.3500000 0.25000000 0.4000000
#> 9   5  2  8 0.3333333 0.13333333 0.5333333
#> 10  3  4  8 0.2000000 0.26666667 0.5333333
#> 11  3  2  1 0.5000000 0.33333333 0.1666667
#> 12  8  1  5 0.5714286 0.07142857 0.3571429
#> 13  7 10  3 0.3500000 0.50000000 0.1500000
#> 14  5 10  5 0.2500000 0.50000000 0.2500000
#> 15  1  4  4 0.1111111 0.44444444 0.4444444
#> 16  9  6  1 0.5625000 0.37500000 0.0625000
#> 17  5  7  7 0.2631579 0.36842105 0.3684211
#> 18  7  3  7 0.4117647 0.17647059 0.4117647
#> 19  2  9  5 0.1250000 0.56250000 0.3125000
#> 20  4  1  5 0.4000000 0.10000000 0.5000000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here are the benchmarks on the existing data:

```r
library(dplyr)  
  have <-
    data.frame(
      x1 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
      x2 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE),
      x3 = sample(1:10, 20, replace = TRUE)
    )
  
f1 <- function(){
  have |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ .x / rowSums(pick(everything())), 
                .names = "{col}_prop"))
}

f2 <- function(){
  have |>
    mutate(
      total = rowSums(across(starts_with("x"))),
      across(starts_with("x"), \(x) x / total, .names = "{.col}_prop")
    )
}

f3 <- function(){
  props <- prop.table(as.matrix(have), 1)
  colnames(props) <- paste(colnames(props), "prop", sep="_")
  cbind(have, 
        props
  )
}
```

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3())
#> Warning in microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3()): less accurate nanosecond times to
#> avoid potential integer overflows
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#>  f1() 2609.199 2701.962 3180.9354 2869.119 3203.515 15608.577   100 a  
#>  f2() 1381.741 1470.875 1903.8781 1546.090 1804.389  9406.753   100  b 
#>  f3()   79.171   98.113  135.9298  113.652  132.143  1543.486   100   c
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I've seen this happen in lots of other places, too.  In small data, the overhead for tidy operations makes them slower.  When the data are bigger, though, the tidy operations outperform some others.  Here are the same benchmarks, but with 20000 obs rather than 20.

```r
  have <-
    data.frame(
      x1 = sample(1:10, 20000, replace = TRUE),
      x2 = sample(1:10, 20000, replace = TRUE),
      x3 = sample(1:10, 20000, replace = TRUE)
    )


microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3())
#> Warning in microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3()): less accurate nanosecond times to
#> avoid potential integer overflows
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#>  f1()  3.164011  3.326145  3.929811  3.671857  3.939916  7.224569   100 a  
#>  f2()  1.646273  1.768474  2.138184  1.893769  2.175686  8.752803   100  b 
#>  f3() 12.781504 14.658791 16.305533 15.854946 16.253732 58.099706   100   c
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes! I had considered `prop.table` -- maybe i'll benchmark this against the `dplyr` solution since i'll be performing this operation on pretty large dataframes.

Comment: @pyll I was just doing the benchmarks, I put them in the answer.

Comment: oh wow! pretty significant difference! thanks!

Comment: @pyll I put up some benchmarks increasing the size of the dataset significantly and the results basically reverse - the tidy stuff is quicker on larger datasets.  This seems to have been a theme in the results I've investigated.

Answer (score 3):

Try `rowSums`, for exmaple

```
> cbind(have, setNames(have / rowSums(have), paste0(names(have), "_prop")))
   x1 x2 x3   x1_prop   x2_prop    x3_prop
1   8  4  8 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.40000000
2   7  7  9 0.3043478 0.3043478 0.39130435
3   2  6  8 0.1250000 0.3750000 0.50000000
4   8  2 10 0.4000000 0.1000000 0.50000000
5   7  3  6 0.4375000 0.1875000 0.37500000
6   8  7  6 0.3809524 0.3333333 0.28571429
7   5  3  7 0.3333333 0.2000000 0.46666667
8   4  8  7 0.2105263 0.4210526 0.36842105
9   7  3  4 0.5000000 0.2142857 0.28571429
10 10  3  5 0.5555556 0.1666667 0.27777778
11  6  9  7 0.2727273 0.4090909 0.31818182
12 10  2  6 0.5555556 0.1111111 0.33333333
13  8  5  3 0.5000000 0.3125000 0.18750000
14 10  5  5 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.25000000
15  4 10  2 0.2500000 0.6250000 0.12500000
16  8 10  1 0.4210526 0.5263158 0.05263158
17  8  8  3 0.4210526 0.4210526 0.15789474
18  7  1  2 0.7000000 0.1000000 0.20000000
19 10  8  8 0.3846154 0.3076923 0.30769231
20  9  7  9 0.3600000 0.2800000 0.36000000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
have |>
  mutate(
    total = rowSums(across(starts_with("x"))),
    across(starts_with("x"), \(x) x / total, .names = "{.col}_prop")
  )
#    x1 x2 x3 total    x1_prop   x2_prop    x3_prop
# 1   8  3  2    13 0.61538462 0.2307692 0.15384615
# 2   7  5  1    13 0.53846154 0.3846154 0.07692308
# 3   2  5  5    12 0.16666667 0.4166667 0.41666667
# 4   5 10 10    25 0.20000000 0.4000000 0.40000000
# 5   1  7  4    12 0.08333333 0.5833333 0.33333333
# 6   5  5  1    11 0.45454545 0.4545455 0.09090909
# 7  10  7  9    26 0.38461538 0.2692308 0.34615385
# 8   1  6  5    12 0.08333333 0.5000000 0.41666667
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor, for the quick response! Picking Maël's answer as it doesn't require the intermediate total column, and is otherwise the same as yours.